# 32 bit Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS lower GPU Memory

Tags: pi-2, ubuntu, video, server

I have a raspberry pi 2 with ubuntu sever installed and need to know how to lower the gpu settings from 64 megs to 16 megs.

Ubuntu Server does not come with raspi-config installed.

Answer (score 2):

This is an option set in [/boot/config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#what-is-config-txt), presuming Ubuntu mounts the first partition there:

```
gpu_mem=16
```

It may be mounted on a slightly different path in a subdirectory of `/boot`, try `find /boot config.txt`.<sup>1</sup>  Also, because it is in the small first partition on the card formatted vfat, you should be able to access it from any computer.

You need to reboot for any changes in `config.txt` to take effect.

> Ubuntu Server does not come with raspi-config installed.

It's just a shell script and currently can be downloaded from: https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config

---

1. Another, more bulletproof method is `mount | grep mmcblk0`, since `/dev/mmcblk0` is the SD card, and it's partitions are `/dev/mmcblk0p1` (the boot partition), `/dev/mmcblk0p1`, etc.  If `mmcblk0p1` isn't there, just mount it yourself.

Comment: I don't have a config.txt file when I check my /boot dir and installing raspi-config I don't think that will work with ubuntu

Comment: The first partition of the SD card **must be a vfat partition** containing some specific files, **regardless of the distro** since otherwise the Pi would not boot, period.  So it is there on the card.  I think `config.txt` may not actually be required, but I would be very surprised if it were not there.  In any case, try `find /boot bootcode.bin`, since that does need to be there.  If it isn't, the boot partition can be mounted wherever and accessed, it is the first partition on the drive, `/dev/mmcblk0p1`, I've edited in an easier way to find that above.

Comment: If the information here still leaves you perplexed, then very seriously and honestly: As someone obviously new to both the Pi and linux, you are making a big mistake not using the most widespread distro in common use, ie., Raspbian/RpiOS, for which there is tons of documentation and help available.  If you don't need this (but it seems clear that you do), you are going to find yourself wasting a lot of time up a creek listening to crickets.